# getting "Provider cannot be found ..." error in vb.net. Using Access with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Using
VB.Net 2008
Microsoft Office - Access 2010

```
    '''con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    con.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Softwares\SalesPurchase.mdb")'''
```

Also tried

'''con.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=D:\Softwares\SalesPurchase.mdb")'''

getting *Provider cannot be found.it may not be properly installed* error in vb.net. Using Access with VB.net.
there is another project with a similar connection string...that works fine...

Comment: Check the bitness of your app, even compare it to the one that works.  Maybe your only have the 32bit Jet driver installed but compiling a 64bit app for example

Comment: Please don't use ADODB in new code. Switch to ADO.net.

Comment: _similar connection string_ - what exactly the difference between the working and non-working connection strings?

Comment: You might need to install the ACE 16 providers, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920 (use either the 32bit or 64bit installer, as appropriate). But, if so, this would not explain why another app is working.